# What is "prep" in "leftover prep"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am not sure what "prep" means in this sentence from an [NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/17/magazine/leftovers-savory-tart-potato-radicchio.html):

> As usual, the tidy nook was stacked with plastic containers of odds and ends, **leftover prep** from the night before, set aside for staff meal.

I thought it possibly means "prepared food," but this usage doesn't seem to be supported by dictionaries. What does "prep" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prep = preparation. I worked in a pizza shop we referred to jobs such as. Opening packets of food, mushrooms, capsicum, tins of pineapple, Putting them into steel containers in the fridge in rows as **"Prep"**.

There is a pizza making bench filled with such containers. When the mushrooms run out we can go grab a "prepared" container from the main fridge and just replace the empty one at the pizza making bench. Its very busy at dinner time!

Given the mention of plastic containers I would imagine something like that!